# Munin, apache and how to password protect munin

Tags: apache2, password-protection, munin

I am using apache2 and munin server on Ubuntu.  How do I password protect domain.com/munin with this username and password

```
admin/test101
```

Here is the location of my munin htmldir:

```
htmldir /var/cache/munin/www
```

Answer (score 12):

You could add basic authication to apache folder using .htaccess
If you munin locate at `/var/www/munin` , you can do like this
edit file `/var/www/munin/.htaccess` , put the follow content there

```
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Members Only"
   AuthUserFile /var/www/munin/.htpasswd
   <limit GET PUT POST>
   require valid-user
   </limit>
```

run command `htpasswd /var/www/munin/.htpasswd admin` to set password for admin user