# How to password protect Munin directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess

I followed [Munin, apache and how to password protect munin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128394/munin-apache-and-how-to-password-protect-munin) and have added .htaccess file in /var/www/munin with this code

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/munin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

I have also generated .htpasswd file with apache utils has it has the username and md5 password. Now after reloading and restarting apache, I can still see example.com/munin content.

I am running rails on example.com but I don't think that has anything to do with munin which resides on different path. Can you suggest me what I am missing out or if there is any other way using which I can password protect munin content ?

Comment: Do you have access to apache .conf files?

Comment: Yes. I have added the same code in apache.conf file too, still the directory is not password protected.